# JavaScript - Storing .textContent of an element in a variable and accesing it in a function

Tags: javascript

i want to make simple two functions. I have a div with a text and an image. I want to change  text in the div element on mouseover and change it back on mouseout.

```
<body>
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

Firstly, before the functions i stored the text of the div element in global variable:

```
var x = document.getElementById("image").textContent;
```

On mouse over i am applying this function to change the text and it works fine:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    var text = previewPic.getAttribute ("alt");
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = text;}
```

On mouseout i want to apply this function:

```
function unDo(){
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = x;}
or     
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML.textContent = x;
```

but neither does work, can someone explain me, how i can store a text of my div, and use it again on mouseout? I can change text on mouseover, but i don't understand how to change it on mouseout. Thank you for your answers

Comment: Your code works for me, you can check it here : https://jsfiddle.net/k38Ljmng/

Comment: `.innerHTML.textContent` doesn't make sense

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe some stupid, simple mistake.. I am putting my whole html and js code: https://jsfiddle.net/drh7j30y/ 
And i see that it works here in this jsfiddle editor, but it does not work for me on my PC, i get "undefined" on mouseout

Comment: Try moving the `<script>` tags to the bottom, above `</body>`. My guess is that when the `var x =` line runs, `#image` isn't ready yet

Comment: It worked! Thank you Hassan. So in general i should always put my <script> somewhere in the bottom? That doesn't look nice... :)